# How to fill up the Cartesian plane with randomly distributed points?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

In matlab, how to fill up the Cartesian plane with randomly distributed points?

That is, for each coordinate x(i,j) in the graph, a point is placed or is not placed based on some random criteria (for example a point is placed there iff a random number is > 0).

Seems like this should be easy to implement, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `rand` as usual,

```
A=rand(N,M)
```

will create a matrix of size NxM of random numbers between 0 and 1 (rand(N) will create a NxN matrix) . You can then select `A>0.9` to select only those point at which A>0.9...

For example:

```
A=rand(50)>0.9;
imshow(A);
```

[image]